# C# Class Selecting Dates of Current Quarter instead of Previous Quarter

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have a C# class that serves as a Sales Reporting Engine. So basically it gets the figures from the database depending on the date range the user has selected.

The user can select dates in two ways - either by a specific date range, or by quarter (i.e. Current Quarter, Previous Quarter).

When the system was handed over to us, the Previous Quarter option was functional, however now it just grabs the same dates as the current quarter (I'm not sure why, the source code for this section has not been changed at all).

I've been looking at it for ages trying to figure out what's going on, because as I said it did function correctly before. I was hoping a fresh pair of eyes might help? I've debugged through the code, and when I select the GetPreviousQuarter it just calculates the GetCurrentQuarterDates.

Here is the switch statement that is called when the user chooses to view information by quarter:

```
switch (reportRequest.SelectedPeriod)
{
    case SalesReportRequest.SalesReportPeriod.Today: // Today
        startDate = DateTime.Today;
        endDate = DateTime.Today.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 23, 59, 59, 59));
        break;
    case SalesReportRequest.SalesReportPeriod.Yesterday:
        startDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
        endDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).Add(new TimeSpan(0, 23, 59, 59, 59));
        break;
    case SalesReportRequest.SalesReportPeriod.Last7Days:
        ReportDateRange dr3 = GetDatesOfLastSevenDays();
        startDate = dr3.StartDate;
        endDate = dr3.EndDate;
        break;
    case SalesReportRequest.SalesReportPeriod.CurrentQuarter: // Current Quarter.
        ReportDateRange dr = GetDatesOfCurrentQuarter();
        startDate = dr.StartDate;
        endDate = dr.EndDate;
        break;
    case SalesReportRequest.SalesReportPeriod.PreviousQuarter: // Previous Quarter.
        ReportDateRange dr1 = GetDatesOfPreviousQuarter();
        startDate = dr1.StartDate;
        endDate = dr1.EndDate;
        break;
    case SalesReportRequest.SalesReportPeriod.CurrentYear: // Current Year.
        ReportDateRange dr2 = GetDatesOfCurrentYear();
        startDate = dr2.StartDate;
        endDate = dr2.EndDate;
        break;
}
```

So then when the Previous Quarter option is selected,  GetDatesOfPreviousQuarter() is called:

```
public ReportDateRange GetDatesOfPreviousQuarter()
{
    var dtmValue = DateTime.Now;
    return DatesOfQuarter(dtmValue);
}
```

This then calls DatesOfQuarter:

```
public ReportDateRange DatesOfQuarter(DateTime dtmValue)
{
    var intQuarter = (int)Math.Ceiling(dtmValue.Month / 3M);

    var intLastMonthOfQuarter = intQuarter * 3; 
    var intFirstMonthOfQuarter = intLastMonthOfQuarter - 2;
    var intLastDayOfQuarter = DateTime.DaysInMonth(dtmValue.Year, intLastMonthOfQuarter);

    ReportDateRange dateRange = new ReportDateRange
    {
        StartDate = new DateTime(dtmValue.Year, intFirstMonthOfQuarter, 1),
        EndDate = new DateTime(dtmValue.Year, intLastMonthOfQuarter, intLastDayOfQuarter)
    };

    return dateRange;
}
```

Any help is appreciated and I can provide more information if needed.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Just because some people were asking for it:

```
    public ReportDateRange GetDatesOfCurrentQuarter()
    {
        var dtmValue = DateTime.Now;
        return DatesOfQuarter(dtmValue);
    }
```

Comment: The code for `GetDatesOfPreviousQuarter` and `DatesOfQuarter` both look correct to me. Are you getting the correct `reportRequest.SelectedPeriod` requested initially?

Comment: Yeah, I've nearly triple checked it at this stage and everything is as it should be. I did try the DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3) that you had posted previously and this seems to pick out the correct dates. Still doesn't solve the mystery of how it worked before though :S

Comment: Comment deleted - ignore me... I'm going insane - sorry! There's got to be something simple in this code...

Comment: Hmm... DatesOfQuarter gets called with DateTime.Now as parameter. Are you sure this is correct? DatesOfQuarter() seems to be a generic method, so the fault probably isn't there.

Comment: :) I'm not sure if you saw my previous comment under your deleted answer, but GetDatesOfCurrentQuarter is the exact same as the GetDatesOfPrevious quarter - which I'm guessing shouldn't be the case? But again, just can't understand why it worked up until now.

Comment: @Rewinder, thanks for the reply. Yeah, I'm thinking this is where the fault lies. I've changed it to DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3) on suggestion from Stuart and that seems to be working fine. I guess I'm really just trying to work out now, how the whole thing used to function before!! :)

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that we just started a new quarter 3 days ago?

Comment: I've tested the code... it's working OK for me!

Comment: I thought that too at first ;-) however it's been giving trouble for about 2 weeks or so. And if I select the previous quarter dates through the date selector, I can see information that's not showing up for the PRevious Quarter option.

Comment: Is that the orignal code Stuart?

Comment: No - sorry to confuse - it's with the fixed code - with AddMonths(-3) - I really think this code MUST have changed since the original - best to go back and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you also post the code of `GetDatesOfCurrentQuarter`?

My guess is that a simple fix might be to change:

```
public ReportDateRange GetDatesOfPreviousQuarter()
{
    var dtmValue = DateTime.Now;
    return DatesOfQuarter(dtmValue);
}
```

to

```
public ReportDateRange GetDatesOfPreviousQuarter()
{
    var dtmValue = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);
    return DatesOfQuarter(dtmValue);
}
```

Comment: Hi Stuart, I was thinking it was only something simple like that, however I just can't understand how it DID work before (I've been told anyway - I didn't create the system) :S...GetDatesOfCurrentQuarter is actually the exact same as GetDatesOfPreviousQuarter, which is also confusing. I'll give your answer a try anyway, thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Also... just to be really careful here... check with whoever is in accounts about when your quarter's start/finish - sometimes accounts can change quarter start/end dates because of weekends, holidays, etc!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: In your edited question it is now apparent that the `GetDatesOfCurrenQuarter()` method and the `GetDatesOfPreviousQuarter()` method are identical.

The problem is that `GetDatesOfPreviousQuarter()` method incorrectly calls the `DatesOfQuarter()` method with the *current* date.

Your quarter calculation is correct. The `M` correctly identifies the dividend as a decimal for the Ceiling calulation. The `Ceiling` calculation is used for "rounding the result upwards" to an integer. This is subsequently cast to an `int` value of the correct Quarter which the datetime belongs to.

In other words: The DatesOfQuarter method will correctly return a structure with the start and end dates for the quarter which the provided date belongs to.

I think the solution to your problem is to have the following two methods:

```
 public ReportDateRange GetDatesOfCurrentQuarter() 
 {     
      var dtmValue = DateTime.Now;     
      return DatesOfQuarter(dtmValue); 
 }
```

and

```
 public ReportDateRange GetDatesOfPreviousQuarter() 
 {     
      var dtmValue = DateTime.Now;     
      return DatesOfQuarter(dtmValue.AddMonths(-3)); 
 }
```

It is beyond the clairvoyance of the SO community to ascertain whether this code never really worked or whether this is a bug was recently introduced by a coworker who managed to hide his trail (and currently denies involvement due to the bad logic)

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx) includes classes for various Calendar Periods like Week, Month, Quarter, Halfyear:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void CalendarYearTimePeriodsSample()
{
  DateTime moment = new DateTime( 2011, 8, 15 );
  Console.WriteLine( "Calendar Periods of {0}:", moment.ToShortDateString() );
  // > Calendar Periods of 15.08.2011:
  Console.WriteLine( "Year     : {0}", new Year( moment ) );
  Console.WriteLine( "Halfyear : {0}", new Halfyear( moment ) );
  Console.WriteLine( "Quarter  : {0}", new Quarter( moment ) );
  Console.WriteLine( "Month    : {0}", new Month( moment ) );
  Console.WriteLine( "Week     : {0}", new Week( moment ) );
  Console.WriteLine( "Day      : {0}", new Day( moment ) );
  Console.WriteLine( "Hour     : {0}", new Hour( moment ) );
  // > Year     : 2011; 01.01.2011 - 31.12.2011 | 364.23:59
  // > Halfyear : HY2 2011; 01.07.2011 - 31.12.2011 | 183.23:59
  // > Quarter  : Q3 2011; 01.07.2011 - 30.09.2011 | 91.23:59
  // > Month    : August 2011; 01.08.2011 - 31.08.2011 | 30.23:59
  // > Week     : w/c 33 2011; 15.08.2011 - 21.08.2011 | 6.23:59
  // > Day      : Montag; 15.08.2011 - 15.08.2011 | 0.23:59
  // > Hour     : 15.08.2011; 00:00 - 00:59 | 0.00:59
} // CalendarYearTimePeriodsSample
```

The calculation is based on the .NET **CultureInfo.Calendar**. Any period provides **GetNextXxx** and **GetPreviousXxx** methods:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void GetDaysOfPastQuarter( DateTime moment,
       out DateTime firstDay, out DateTime lastDay )
{
  TimeCalendar calendar = new TimeCalendar(
    new TimeCalendarConfig { YearBaseMonth = YearMonth.October } );
  Quarter quarter = new Quarter( moment, calendar );
  Quarter pastQuarter = quarter.GetPreviousQuarter();

  firstDay = pastQuarter.FirstDayStart;
  lastDay = pastQuarter.LastDayStart;
} // GetDaysOfPastQuarter
```